# How to hide a content from being display on the screen but display only in the source code?

Tags: html, css, show-hide

I'm running a Wordpress site and having a tag on the site is a good practice for SEO purpose.

But it is taking a lot of spaces and I figure that not many people will actually find anything using tags. I guess it is only good for SEO purpose like google to index them or something like that.

The question is how can I hide that content and stop it from being display on the screen but not on the source code and not to take the space, meaning I can use that space to display something else but that tags still exist in the source code.

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that this may be considered a black-hat practice by google and get your site removed from the index. In general, if your content that differs significantly for users and search engines, you are setting yourself up for getting penalized.

Comment: @steveax wow I never thought of that at all. I think this `SEO` stuff is very critical I was just thinking of putting some other useful information instead in that spot because I tracked the click on my site and never have any click on those tags and felt maybe is not useful at all to have them in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `display: none` on the content you want to hide, that won't reserve the space, will hide your information and you'll still be able to see it in the source code :).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `display: none`, I would suggest using HTML meta tags, which always get my pages good indexes in search engines.  The meta description tag and meta keywords tags are particularly useful.  All meta tags are invisible on pages but show up in the source code, by the way.

Here's an introduction to HTML geared towards Wordpress users:
http://om4.com.au/client/html-for-bloggers/

Here are the basic meta tags you should use:

```
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials" />
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript" />
<meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

you simply add these to your pages you want SEO on and then change the content to match your site.

Here's a little more info on meta tags:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Edit:

Nowadays, you can't just hide content that is purely for SEO because Google will lower your site in the search rankings. Instead, just make sure you have good content on your site and use heavily things like the image `alt` attribute.

**Here's a snippet from Google about hidden text or links for SEO**: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353

> Hiding text or links in your content to manipulate Google’s search
>   rankings can be seen as deceptive and is a violation of Google’s
>   Webmaster Guidelines. **Text (such as excessive keywords) can be
>   hidden in several ways, including**:
>
> - Using white text on a white background Locating text behind an image
> - Using CSS to position text off-screen Setting the font size to 0
> - Hiding a link by only linking one small character—for example, a    hyphen in the middle of a paragraph

Comment: Search engines have ignored meta tags (and anything else not surfaced to the user) for ranking for years.

Comment: Actually, my meta description tag always shows up on search engines and even overrides the content on the actual page occasionally.

Comment: Description tags are sometimes shown in results listings, but are not used for rank. [Google has stated this definitively](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)

Comment: Bing, however, does use it so it's simply an alternative.

Comment: Well I actually don't prefer to mess with the meta tags because I have plugin that generate depend on my posts differently. but thanks for the display:none; info.

Answer (score 0):

What I do, is, I present the page best for SEO, until I sense user interaction (mouse move, mouse down, etc), then the fancy stuff, text graphics and slow graphics start loading. I think most search engines would ignore anything with display:none.

Comment: Are you saying that if is invisible then google will ignore and not even index that?

Comment: Pretty sure. But pay attention to what steveax commented on your post. You do NOT want google to get mad at you.